# Package NDC Query

Tags: openfda

I am trying to query OpenFDA to get some data on the following product:

https://ndclist.com/ndc/52380-0001/package/52380-0001-3

I have tried querying 52380000103, 5238000013, 5238000103 and 523800013 with no luck.  I'm hoping there is someone here in the community that can shed some light on why I am not getting any results.

I also tried an FDB query for those of you who use First Data Bank with no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bill,

Here's are two queries that might work for you:

**Against the openFDA NDC SPL Data Elements API**

https://api.fda.gov/other/nsde.json?search=package_ndc:52380-0001-3

**Against the openFDA Drug Product Labeling API**

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.package_ndc:52380-0001-3

Comment: Thank you.  Why would such a query return results for a product with a different NDC?  This query returns a result for an NDC number: 65044221503.

Comment: Ahh... I just needed to put quotes around the NDC.  Thank you!